# Experimentally measure penetration depth for metamaterials?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, metamaterials

I have simulated a high penentration metasurface design and want to fabricate it. |E|^2 decays above the metasurface with very long ~ 1um decay length.
What would be a good experimental way to measure the penetration length?

Comment: I’m a little unclear what you mean by “penetration depth”. Could you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for replying! Clarification on penetration depth: it's the decay length of |E|^2 away from matasurface. e.g. if |E|^2~exp(-x/x0), x0 is the penetration length.

Comment: okay, so this isn’t a transmissive metasurface? Is it operating in reflection or is this some sort of bound mode? Is the field decaying into vacuum or a dielectric or a metal? Is there a background field you want to distinguish from this decaying field? What’s the length scale you anticipate? Etc etc; we would need a lot more information to begin to answer this question.

Comment: It's operating in reflection for biosensing. We put cells on top of the metasurface and light comes/reflects below the metasurface. The field is decaying into water in operation. But in theory the high penetration length works in any environment such as air/vacuum and without the cell as long as the incident light is at res=5um. There is no background field. The decay length is ~1um and metasurface unit cell is ~500nmx50nm and the sample chip with metasurface arrays are ~ 1cmx1cm.